# The [corruption] tag is corrupted

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

I've checked out some of the questions with [corruption](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/corruption), and the more I read the more I'm convinced it's unhelpful as it is.

Corruption of files, of streams, of download, upload, screen, filesystem, usb, hard drive, Word document, ad absurdum.

We need to remove this tag; it has so many meanings depending the context that it makes no sense if it's alone in a question.

Comment: You spelled the title wrong! **Your title is corrupted**

Comment: @Braiam - Based on the history of question that surround corrupted files, I would rather see that entire topic not be allowed, in three years I have might have seen maybe 1 actual real question about a corrupted file. I would estimate I have read at least 7,000 questions in my 3+ years here. I view about 25-50 questions daily.  This topic is used to spam for some odd reason, it shouldn't be like that, but it is.

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is that people don't keep backups and expect there to be a magic solution to recover corrupt files. Which is where quite a few spammy tools promise to have a solution for. Ideally we'd have one canonical question that deals with this, but I don't see how this is practical either.

Comment: Agree. Especially answers of questions about recovering corrupted/lost files and hardware are full of spam.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi  I was tempted to use zalgo :P

Comment: I sometimes come to Meta and see no answer to a "question" with several upvotes. I freak out then remember it's Meta.